# While try get values from XML file it display javascript error.

Tags: javascript, xml

When I try to open the **XML** File its show Access Denied javascript error.

**This is my XML code:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<company test="test">
    <employee id="001" >John</employee>
    <turnover>
        <year id="2000">100,000</year>
        <year id="2001">140,000</year>  
        <year id="2002">200,000</year>
    </turnover>
</company>
```

**This in my JavaScript code.**

```
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Employee.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

I want to get the values from XML Files.

Any one please tell me how to get value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it like this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Comment: I try this but now also, It display the Access Denied JavaScript error. Pls tell how to load XML file in my local machine.

Comment: if you are using a localhost,you can give a url like this,http://localhost/xml/employee.xml then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you're hitting the cross-origin security checks in your browser. In particular, a webpage loaded from a file:// url generally can't access other documents at file:// urls. If you happen to be using Firefox, setting the `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` preference to `false` in `about:config` will let it work. The other option is to serve both files from a real web server, and from the same domain.